# Check if an array contains all array values from another array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$all = array
(
    0 => 307,
    1 => 157,
    2 => 234,
    3 => 200,
    4 => 322,
    5 => 324
);
$search_this = array
(
    0 => 200,
    1 => 234
);
```

I would like to find out if `$all` contains all `$search_this` values and return `true` or `false`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking to see if one array's elements are in another array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523796/checking-to-see-if-one-arrays-elements-are-in-another-array-in-php)

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu Not quite a duplicate: Your given link has to do with checking if ANY elements are contained in another array, not if ALL elements are contained in another.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Look at [array_intersect()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

```
$containsSearch = count(array_intersect($search_this, $all)) === count($search_this);
```

Or for associative array, look at [array_intersect_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php).

Or for recursive compare of sub-arrays, try:

```
<?php

namespace App\helpers;

class Common {
    /**
     * Recursively checks whether $actual parameter includes $expected.
     *
     * @param array|mixed $expected Expected value pattern.
     * @param array|mixed $actual Real value.
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function intersectsDeep(&$expected, &$actual): bool {
        if (is_array($expected) && is_array($actual)) {
            foreach ($expected as $key => $value) {
                if (!static::intersectsDeep($value, $actual[$key])) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        } elseif (is_array($expected) || is_array($actual)) {
            return false;
        }
        return (string) $expected == (string) $actual;
    }
}
```

Comment: You know you can omit both `count()` calls?

Comment: @Wrikken Can't the values get reordered during `array_intersect()`? I mean, `['a', 'b'] != ['b', 'a']`.

Comment: @exizt: `array_intersect()` does not alter the input arrays, so `$search_this` & `$all` are safe (it just returns an output). The function signature is `array array_intersect ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] )` (safe). If it would/could alter them, it would be `array array_intersect ( array &$array1 , array &$array2 [, array &$... ] )` (possible altering of input arguments). Also, the keys of `$search_this` are _preserve_, and the order of the first array is kept. So, both key/value pairs, as their order, match.

Comment: And even then: [array comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php): _"`==` TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs."_, so the order doesn't even matter (use `===` for that)

Comment: This answer assumes that the $all array only contains unique values. If this is not the case, one may use the array_unique function on the $all array in the array_intersects function.

Answer (score 324):

The previous answers are all doing more work than they need to. Just use [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php). This is the simplest way to do it:

```
$containsAllValues = !array_diff($search_this, $all);
```

That's all you have to do.

Comment: What about of using `empty(array_diff($search_this, $all));`?

Comment: ! operator on array will always return true. Use @Miguel 's suggestion: empty(array_diff($search_this, $all));

Comment: The original answer works because an empty array evaluates as false in PHP.  Using `empty()` also works, but the `!` operator does work fine.

Comment: @Miguel an empty array in this context is treated as falsey, there is no need to use  `empty`.

Comment: This should actually be flipped, so it reads `$containsAllValues = !array_diff($all, $search_this);`

-----
Example: `$containsAllValues = !array_diff($all = ['a', 'b', 'c'], $search_this = ['c', 'c', 'c']);`
>> result false

-----
Example: `$containsAllValues = !array_diff($search_this = ['c', 'c', 'c'], $search_this = ['a', 'b', 'c']);`
>> Result true

Comment: @bluegman991 That suggestion doesn't work according to my understanding of the question, which is that they want it to return true if every value in `$search_this` is a value that exists in `$all`.  So for the arrays `$search_this = ['c', 'c', 'c']` and `$all = ['a', 'b', 'c']` it should return `true`, as my original answer does, because `'c'` exists in `$all`.

Comment: this answer doesnt work on multidimensional arrays! different values on level 2 or deeper are ignored

Comment: @Sliq This question isn't about multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 15):

A bit shorter with [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
$musthave = array('a','b');
$test1 = array('a','b','c');
$test2 = array('a','c');

$containsAllNeeded = 0 == count(array_diff($musthave, $test1));

// this is TRUE

$containsAllNeeded = 0 == count(array_diff($musthave, $test2));

// this is FALSE
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you're looking for the intersect function

```
array array_intersect ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $ ... ] )
```

`array_intersect()` returns an array containing all values of array1 that are 
 present in all the arguments. Note that keys are preserved.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```php
function array_keys_exist($searchForKeys = array(), $searchableArray) {
    $searchableArrayKeys = array_keys($searchableArray);

    return count(array_intersect($searchForKeys, $searchableArrayKeys)) == count($searchForKeys); 
}
```