# php check if an array only contains element values of another array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to check if an array only contains allowed element values (are available in another array).

Example:

```
$allowedElements = array('apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'melon');

checkFunction(array('apple', 'orange'), $allowedElements); // OK

checkFunction(array('pear', 'melon', 'dog'), $allowedElements); // KO invalid array('dog') elements
```

What is the best way to implement this checkFunction($a, $b) function?

Answer (score 5):

```
count($array) == count(array_intersect($array,$valid));
```

.. or come to think of it;

```
$array == array_intersect($array,$valid);
```

Note that this would yield `true` if `(string)$elementtocheck=(string)$validelement`, so in essence, only usable for scalars. If you have more complex values in your array (arrays, objects), this won't work. To make *that* work, we alter it a bit:

```
sort($array);//order matters for strict
sort($valid);
$array === array_intersect($valid,$array);
```

... *assuming* that the current order does not matter / `sort()` is allowed to be called.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/array_intersect) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9655722/1438393). Here's a little function:

```
function CheckFunction($myArr, $allowedElements) 
{
    $check = count(array_intersect($myArr, $allowedElements)) == count($myArr);

    if($check) {
        return "Input array contains only allowed elements";
    } else {
        return "Input array contains invalid elements";
    }
}
```

### **[Demo!](http://codepad.org/YdlR08IQ)**

Comment: That does not work like you think it does. [Did you test it](http://codepad.org/Gii7qsUq)?

Comment: @Wrikken: you were right. I've updated the answer. Please remove the downvote :)

Comment: As soon as you implement non-scalar comparison :P (BTW: do we _need_ 2 answers saying `array_intersect`?)

Comment: That's still lossy comparison, but my downvote is at least gone as it would suffice for the OPs testcase ;)