# PHP check if one array doesn't have other values than another array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to check if an array doesn't have other values than the other but in_array() didn't worked so I guess it can't be done with in_array();

for example

```
<?php
$arr1 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$arr2 = array(1,2,9);
if(/*all values in $arr2 are in $arr1*/){ 
  /*return true*/
}
else{
  /*return false*/
}
/*this examle should return false*/
?>
```

or

```
<?php
$arr1 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$arr2 = array(1,2,6);
if(/*all values in $arr2 are in $arr1*/){ 
  /*return true*/
}
else{
  /*return false*/
}
/*this examle should return true*/
?>
```

how can I do this?

Comment: There's a whack of array functions for this: array_merge, array_diff, array_intersect, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255500/php-check-if-an-array-only-contains-element-values-of-another-array)

> ```
> count($array) == count(array_intersect($array,$valid));
> ```
>
> .. or come to think of it;
>
> ```
> $array == array_intersect($array,$valid);
> ```
>
> Note that this would yield `true` if
>   `(string)$elementtocheck=(string)$validelement`, so in essence, only
>   usable for scalars. If you have more complex values in your array
>   (arrays, objects), this won't work. To make *that* work, we alter it a
>   bit:
>
> ```
> sort($array);//order matters for strict
> sort($valid);
> $array === array_intersect($valid,$array);
> ```
>
> ... *assuming* that the current order does not matter / `sort()` is
>   allowed to be called.

Comment: I don't have more complex data just numbers thats why I posted an example like this. And thanks it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is the conditional you are looking for:

```
if (count(array_diff($arr2, $arr1)) == 0) {
```

Comment: Thanks, I like your answer but I already accepted one when I saw yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_intersect()` function:

```
if (array_intersect($arr1, $arr2) == $arr2) {
  // $arr2 has only elements from $arr1
} else {
  // $arr2 has not only elements from $arr1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `array_diff`:

Example

```
public function checkSameContents($arr1, $arr2) {
    $diff = array_diff($arr1, $arr2); // returns "unsame" elements in array 
    return count($diff) === 0;
}
```

This function will return true if the arrays have the same contents, but false if not.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
$arr1 == $arr2
```

Or you can use a function

```
<?php
function compareArrays(Array $a, Array $b){
  if(count($a) != count($b)){
    return false;
  }
  foreach($a as $value){
    if( !in_array($value, $b) ){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
?>
```

This is only an example but you could do it this way.