# PHP return true if all values in 1 array are present in array 2

Tags: php, arrays

im looking for a function like array_intersect but instead of returning what values are present in 2 arrays it should return TRUE only if all values in array 1 are contained in array 2.

For example:

```
$first_array = array(0=>1, 1=>4, 2=>8)
$second_array = array(0=>9, 1=>8, 2=>7, 3=>1, 4=>3, 5=>4)
```

If you compare both arrays, all the values in $first_array are present in $second_array which are 1, 4 and 8 so the function should return true. Is there a function out there that can do this?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9655722/365188

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function compare($first_array, $second_array){
         if(empty(array_diff($first_array,$second_array))){
                return true;
         }else{
                return false;
         }
}
```

Try this. Anyone see any error please edit it.

Comment: Thanks, that looks nice. Would this also work? if(array_diff($first_array, $second_array)==0 { return TRUE};

Comment: @CainNuke sorry , that's beyond my knowledge. You need to try it yourself.

Comment: It works for me, seems like we get the same results with both methods. I like yours better though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution 
if you don't want to use `array_diff()`

```
<?php


  $a = array("c","b","a");
  $b = array("a","b","c");

  if(ArrayCompare($a , $b)){
    echo "100%";
    } else {
      echo "NOT";
    }

  function ArrayCompare($array1 , $array2) {

  $c = 0;
  foreach($array1 as $v) {
    if(in_array($v , $array2)) {
      $c++;    
    }
  }

  if(count($array2) == $c) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function compare($arr1,$arr2)
{
$arr3=Array();
$k=0;
for($i=0;$i<count($arr1);$i++)
{
if(in_array($arr1[$i],$arr2))
$arr3[$k]=$arr1[$i];
$k++
}

if(count($arr3)==count($arr1))
return true;
else
return false;
}
?>
```