# php check if array part of another array

Tags: php, arrays

if I have:

```
$hold = array(1, 1, 4); // this will be true
$allArr = array(1, 1, 3, 4, 5);
$containsHold = count(array_intersect($hold, $allArr)) == count($hold);
```

$containhold is true and it is ok, but if I have next:

```
$hold = array(1, 1, 1); // this will be false but it is true
$allArr = array(1, 1, 3, 4, 5);
$containsHold = count(array_intersect($hold, $allArr)) == count($hold);
```

This return true, but I need to be false because $hold contain three 1

Comment: First of all read array of php, before asking this question. Still you got your answer in array_intersect (php array function) documentation. If not able to understand try this link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655687/php-check-if-array-contains-all-array-values-from-another-array

Comment: It is not answer for my example.Try $hold = array(1, 1, 1); This with array_intersect return true!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i uderstand correctly you shuld count the values of each array
and than compare value and counts....:

```
function arrayContainArray($array, $array1){
    $c = array_count_values($array);
    $c1 = array_count_values($array1);
    foreach($c as $k=>$n){
        if(!isset($c1[$k]) || $c1[$k]<$n){ return false; }
    }
    return true;
}

$containsHold = arrayContainArray($hold, $allArr);
```