# Check if values in array are in another array using Laravel Validation

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-validation

I want to check if all the values of my input, an array, are in another array. For example:

```
$my_arr = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'];

Validator::make($request, [
            'item' => [ /* what do i put here??? */ ],
        ]);
```

I don't think the rule `in` works, because that expects a single value as input, not an array.  `in_array` doesn't work either. I've tried creating a custom rule or closure, but neither of those allow me to pass in a parameter (the array I want to check against). Especially since I want this same functionality for multiple arrays, for different inputs, it would be nice to have a generic rule that works for any array I give it.

If that's not possible, I suppose I need to create a rule for each specific array and use `!array_diff($search_this, $all)` as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22651134/8273161) says. Is there an alternative to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True that `in` doesn't accept an array but a string. So you can just convert the array into a string.

```
$my_arr = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'];

Validator::make($request, [
   'item' => [ 'in:' . implode(',', $my_arr) ],
]);
```

[implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Another better solution might be to use `Illuminate\Validation\Rule`'s `in` method that accepts an array:

```
'item' => [ Rule::in($my_arr) ],
```

[Laravel Validation - Rule::in](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-in)

Comment: Wait, so the validation rule works even if the input is an array? Just checking because that wasn't specified in the Laravel documentation.