# Eval string for wordpress "in_category" workaround outside the loop

Tags: php, wordpress, eval, categories, intersection

In Wordpress you can´t use "in_category" outside the loop, so I created a function that gives me all the categories my article is in and create a "is_category" if statement out of it.

I put my function in my "functions.php":

```
function inCatAlt($catID){
    $allCats = get_categories('child_of='.$catID);

    $childCats = 'is_category('.$catID.') ';
    foreach($allCats as $childCat){
        $childCats.= 'or is_category('.$childCat->cat_ID.') ';
    };

    $allchildCats = trim(trim($childCats, 'or '));
    return $allchildCats;
}
```

and call this in my sidebar, single and so on:

```
echo inCatAlt(13);
```

which gives me this as a string back:

```
"is_category(13) or is_category(16) or is_category(15)"
```

This is exactly what I needed, but now I want to evaluate the string to use it in a if function like this:

```
if(eval(inCatAlt(13))){
 do something
}
```

But it doesn´t work. 
Do I evaluate it wrong or what is the problem? 
If I copy paste the output into the if function it works fine…

Comment: But it's still going to be outside of the loop if it's in the sidebar? I don't see what this solves... Also, is_category can be used outside the loop. You just have to give the page ID as the second parameter: in_category( cat_id, post_id); also you use is_category where I think you mean in_category? is_category can always be used, even outside the loop.

Comment: yeah, i know that in_category doesn´t work but is_category does. I have one cat which has several child-cats. I just want my function to give me automatically all my child cats and make a "is_category" if statement out of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer what I think is the real question. Your proposed solution is extremely bad practice.

Try this:

```
$post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id );
$child_categories = get_categories( array( 'child_of' => $catID ) );

if( count( array_intersect( $post_categories, $child_categories ) ) > 0 )
    // The post exists in one or more of the child categories
```

Comment: [Checking if ANY of an array's elements are in another array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/523796/2943403)