# Display text for users with certain roles

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a piece of text in a custom page--front.tpl.php file. I would like to wrap this in a php if statement so that it is displayed only to two of my site roles. I have the below but it only displays for the "client" role whereas I would also like to display it for the"consultants" role.

```
<?php if (in_array('client', $GLOBALS['user']->roles)):?>
```

## Client profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in_array function should accept multiple search parameters if they are passed as an array. So it should be something like:

```
<?php if (in_array(array('client','consultants'), $GLOBALS['user']->roles)):?>
```

But if that's not working (and it should) you can always use or statement:

```
<?php if (in_array('client', $GLOBALS['user']->roles) || in_array('consultants', $GLOBALS['user']->roles)):?>
```

**Update:** it seems that `in_array()` can't accept an array for first (needle) parameter. Check out this thread on stack overflow:

[Checking to see if one array's elements are in another array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523796/checking-to-see-if-one-arrays-elements-are-in-another-array-in-php)

So `array_intersect()` function should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Milan thanks for the reply. Unfortunate the first option didn't work. I tried the second one and it seems to do the tricky. If i need to make the text display for a large range of user roles though, it might become quite lengthy.

Comment: Updated my answer.