# how to compare 2 arrays using in_array function

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i have 2 arrays i need to compare exactly in the same order, i need to check if each array from classes `subA` and `subB` contains the value from the one in prerequisite.

**my prerequisite array**

```
Array
(
    [s1] => MAT
    [s2] => ENG
    [s3] => PHY
    [s4] => CHE
    [s5] => FRE
)
```

**and my classes array**

```
Array
(
    [subA] => MAT
    [subB] => ENG
)
Array
    (
     [subA] => ENG
     [subB] =>
    )
Array
    (
     [subA] => MAT
     [subB] => PHY
    )
Array
    (
     [subA] => CHE
     [subB] => 
    )
Array
    (
     [subA] => MAT
     [subB] => FRE
    )
```

**my code**

```
$prerequisite = array(
  's1' => 'MAT',
  's2' => 'ENG',
  's3' => 'PHY',
  's4' => 'CHE',
  's5' => 'FRE'
);

$confirmed = TRUE;

$i = 0;
foreach($prerequisite as $p )
{                     
  if( in_array( $prerequisite, $classes[$i] ) )
  {
    // The prerequisite has been met
  }
  else
  {
    // The prerequisite has not been met
    $confirmed = FALSE;
  }
  $i++;
}

if($confirmed == TRUE) { //run insert query here }
```

**expected output**

I need to return TRUE if all prerequisites are met,
need it to find for example:

- if first array from classes `subA` or `subB` matches `s1` value `MAT` from prerequisite array
- if second array from classes `subA` or `subB` matches `s2` value `ENG` from prerequisite array
- if third array from classes `subA` or `subB` matches `s3` value `PHY` from prerequisite array
- if fourth array from classes `subA` or `subB` matches `s4` value `CHE` from prerequisite array
- if fifth array from classes `subA` or `subB` matches `s5` value `FRE` from prerequisite array

**Problem**

I am always getting `FALSE` and not being able to run the insert query

Comment: Can you put the $classes array in your code?

Comment: @Ikillnukes my classes array is coming from a query running before this condition that's why i posted the output of classes array in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `$p`, you're providing an array as the needle argument to in_array(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

If you replace the in_array needle with `$p`, you'll be searching `$classes[$i]` for a single value rather than an entire array.

You also don't seem to need that entire block, just use a ! (not) on the condition rather than checking a condition and using an else block.

```
if( ! in_array( $p, $classes[$i] ) )
{
    $confirmed = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question provides a beautiful use case for the PHP function [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$prerequisite = array(
  's1' => 'MAT',
  's2' => 'ENG',
  's3' => 'PHY',
  's4' => 'CHE',
  's5' => 'FRE'
);

$classes = array(
    array(
        'subA' => 'MAT',
        'subB' => 'ENG',
    ),
    array(
        'subA' => 'ENG',
        'subB' => NULL,
    ),
    array(
        'subA' => 'MAT',
        'subB' => 'PHY',
    ),
    array(
        'subA' => 'CHEx',        // <---- doesn't match the prerequisite
        'subB' => NULL,
    ),
    array(
        'subA' => 'MAT',
        'subB' => 'FRE',
    ),
);

// array_filter() removes the matching classes
$missing = array_filter(
    array_map(
        function(array $class, $pre, $key) {
            // Return $key when the values of both 'subA' and 'subB'...
            // ... are different than the expected prerequisite
            return ($class['subA'] !== $pre && $class['subB'] !== $pre) ? $key : NULL;
        },
        $classes,
        $prerequisite,
        array_keys($prerequisite)
    )
);


// $missing associates the keys of $classes (numbers) to the keys of $prerequisite
// ... for classes that do not match their prerequisite
print_r($missing);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [3] => s4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> This can be an possible duplicate of: [Checking to see if one array's elements are in another array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523796/checking-to-see-if-one-arrays-elements-are-in-another-array-in-php)

You should use **array_intersect** for this approach...

I will answer because there are also another things that you haven't cleared.

```
$prerequisite = array(
  's1' => 'MAT',
  's2' => 'ENG',
  's3' => 'PHY',
  's4' => 'CHE',
  's5' => 'FRE'
);

$classes1 = array(
    "subA" => "MAT",
    "subB" => "ENG"
);

$classes2 = array(
    "subA" => "ENG",
    "subB" => ""
);

if(!empty(array_intersect($prerequisite, $classes1))) { 
    //run insert query here
}
```

You have missed some things:

- You have used `$classes` as a **numeric array** instead of an **associative one**.
- You have missed `$p` in the **foreach**

As you can see, I have created the array from the query that you have told me.

You can see this working on [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5b43129dd8e1bca70b3246c889d57fb2d4a12591)