# search array in another two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am creating a search function in which in need to find matching results from two arrays `$array1` is set of  keywords for which i am performing search in `$array2` which is  multidimensional array

Example of Arrays:

```
$array1 = ['Agriculture & Farming','Modern','Monograms'];
$array2 = [[1,"Agriculture & Farming","Bold","000"],[2,"Agriculture & Farming","Bold","f44336"],[3,"Agriculture & Farming","Bold","E91E63"],[4,"Agriculture & Farming","Bold","9C27B0"],[5,"Agriculture & Farming","Bold","673AB7"],[6,"Agriculture & Farming","Bold","3F51B5"],[7,"Agriculture & Farming","Bold","2196F3"];
```

I need to find matching keywords item id from $arrays2 but its not working
i looped through both arrays and match but wrong results showing

This is how i am trying now but its giving wrong results:

```
foreach($array2 as $itemkey) {

    $k1 = $itemkey[1];
    $k2 = $itemkey[2];
    $k3 = $itemkey[3];
    $ResutItem= $item;

    foreach($array1 as $searckKey ) {

        if ($searckKey == $k1 || $searckKey == $k2 || $searckKey == $k3) {

            echo implode(" ", $ResutItem).
            '<br>';

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking to see if one array's elements are in another array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523796/checking-to-see-if-one-arrays-elements-are-in-another-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).
This will give you an array where key is in what subarray of array2 the match is.
And the values are the matching values.

```
Foreach($array2 as $key => $arr){
    $match[$key] = array_merge([$array2[$key][0]], array_intersect($arr, $array1));
}

Var_dump($match);
```

https://3v4l.org/vVCiQ

Comment: hey one more thing how can i store matching items key  from array2

Comment: I don't understand, that is what you get in $match. Or what are you looking for? Can you give an example output? Edit your question with what you expect

Comment: Updated array example in question what i need is ID of matching item from array2 like in example array  arrays like this [1,"Agriculture & Farming","Bold","000"]... here ID is **1**

Comment: See update, now I use array_merge to add item 0 of the array with the matching parts.

Comment: i am getting id now by using this !empty(array_intersect($people, $criminals)) ..thanks again have a nice day !