# I try to search array in array array_search() PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I try to search array in array, but function doesn't work:

```
$a = [];
$b = [];
array_push($a,"1");
array_push($a,"2");
array_push($b,"2");
dd(array_search($b,$a));
```

How I can search array values in other array?

Comment: array_search($b[0],$a));

Comment: What is your purpose of the search?

Comment: I would use what was advised above but i want to make seach array values in array, not string in array

Comment: You can't search it like that using buit in php functions. You have to write your own code for that. but if you want to get array from $a that match from $b you can do it.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php
At this link Indicated that that needle can as an array and a string. Because i wrote this question here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking to see if one array's elements are in another array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523796/checking-to-see-if-one-arrays-elements-are-in-another-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't simply get that searched by built in function but if you intent to get array that match from $b into $a you can do it by using

```
print_r( array_intersect($a, $b) );
```

**Input**

```
$a = [];
        $b = [];
        array_push($a,"1");
        array_push($a,"2");
        array_push($a, "3");
        array_push($b,"2");
        array_push($b, '1');
        print_r( array_intersect($a, $b) );

        echo !empty(array_intersect($a, $b));
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

Comment: My very thanks, it works as i need.

Comment: glad! that help you in your way.