# Finding if a value in array exists in an second array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays:

```
$selected_symptoms_array = explode(',', $symptoms);
$symptoms_array = explode(',', $disease->symptoms_id);
```

This is a set of IDs, like 8,9,42,68,193,209.
I need to find a match if at least one value matches.

**For example if ID 8 in symptoms_array**

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific.  And add more of your code?

Comment: If you are looking for a value in an array, try `array_search()`.

Comment: Use `array_intersect()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/523798/19926805).
You can use `array_intersect`

```
count(array_intersect($arr1, $arr2))
```

If the return value of `count()` is higher than 0: `$arr1` has at least one same value as `$arr2`