# Checking if a values from array exists in a second array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to check if any of the values from array 1 exist in array 2. I am currently trying to achieve this using a combination of `foreach` and `in_array`:

Array 1:

```
Array
(
    [checkThis1] => 1234567
    [checkThis2] => 7654321
    [checkThis3] => 0101010
)
```

Array 2:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0101010
    [1] => 9324812
)
```

Code:

```
foreach ($array1 as $checkThis) {
        if (in_array($checkThis, $array2)) {
            echo "checkThis exists in array2";
            return true;
        }
        echo "checkThis does not exist in array2";
        return false;
    }
```

As you can see up here the two arrays are formatted the same way so this should cause no issues. For some reason unknown to me this loop always returns false, even though I am sure that the value exists in both of the arrays.

Comment: Don't use `return`s, comment them out and see what the result is. And use `echo "$checkThis ...` instead of `echo "checkThis...`

Comment: Do you mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523796/checking-if-any-of-an-arrays-elements-are-in-another-array

Comment: 1234567 is not in array2. no idea how you are sure about that, but you didn't convince me ;)

Comment: @hakre True! But 0101010 is in array2 :)

Comment: @Luuc: See the first comment: `return` exits the loop as well, but you're not yet done with the work. return `false` only _after_ the foreach body, not within. Within, you only return true, because that is already the outcome (there could be more matches, but it is a match already on first match). Only as long there is not yet a match, you have to go on and go on and can only say after processing all items, that there is no match at all (return false).

Comment: @hakre I've tried this solution and it worked! Now I see what I was doing wrong, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`return`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) ends code execution. Your [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) is only completing its first iteration. If `0101010` was the first item in the first array it would return true. To get the items that exist in both arrays use [`array_intersect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

```php
$arrayOne = [
    'checkThis1' => 1234567,
    'checkThis2' => 7654321,
    'checkThis3' => 0101010
];

$arrayTwo = [0101010, 9324812];

$intersect = array_intersect(array_values($arrayOne), $arrayTwo);
```

To check if any of the items exist in the second array check if the count of the intersect is bigger than 0.

```php
$hasAny = (count(array_intersect(array_values($arrayOne), $arrayTwo)) > 0); // true or false
```

Comment: I see, so if the first checked value does not exist in array 2, the function exits via return? That would make sense of why it does not work :)

Comment: The code that you provided does not show a function, if it is within a function, yes.